# Linking to a shared library that links to another shared library segfaults on exit

Tags: c++, cmake

Unfortunately I have been unable to create a minimal example, but here is the situation. I have one library that links to another, like this:

```
add_library(MainLib MainLib.cpp)

add_library(ChildLib ChildLib.cpp)
target_link_libraries(ChildLib MainLib)
```

I can do this (not using the ChildLib, but rather compiling `ChildLib.cpp` into the executable directly):

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(TestNoLink TestNoLink.cpp ChildLib.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(TestNoLink MainLib)
```

and everything compiles, links, and runs with no problems.

However, if I do this (now using the `ChildLib`):

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(TestChildLink TestChildLink.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(TestChildLink ChildLib) # no need to link to MainLib here because ChildLib already links to MainLib
```

Everything still compiles and links, and it actually runs fine as well, but after it is finished running, it segfaults.

Is there some concept I should be looking for here to figure out what is causing this?

Comment: "Is there some concept ... to figure out what is causing this?"  Bisect the differences until you find the critical step that triggers the problem and you will probably be 95% of the way towards the solution.  It may sound tedious but it's the kind of thing professional software developers find themselves doing often.

Comment: @BrianCain What do you mean "bisect the differences"? The differences in what?

Comment: The differences betweeen "not using the ChildLib" vs "now using the ChildLib".  Does a null ChildLib cause this same problem?  Change `ChildLib.cpp` to contain a single empty function declaration and no static initializers.

Comment: Simpler still might be to just run under a debugger to see what code triggers the segfault.  Is it an `atexit()` handler, e.g.?

Comment: @BrianCain Running with gdb it ends up in a `malloc.c` assembly file with the call stack in dl-fini.c, cxa_finalize.c, and malloc.c, seemingly from a destructor from a third party library that is linked to from `MainLib`. I just don't understand why this would not appear when linking to the same code in a different way (the two ways I showed)?

Comment: Likely suspects are a bug in the library or heap corruption.  If you couldn't reproduce with a minimal example it's likely the latter. In that case use asan to find your bug.

Comment: @BrianCain It seems like asan is similar to valgrind? I've run with valgrind and it seems to exit with no problems. Getting it to go with asan sounds like it will be tough as it seems to be a clang tool and I'm building with g++.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108122/discussion-between-brian-cain-and-david-doria).

Comment: Your question is point-less without a minimal example that shows your problem. Unless you have this example, I'd guess it is no CMake issue, but an actual bug in your C++ code. This would render your question useless. Downvoting until providing an example.

Comment: I have had these kind of errors several times, and always it ended up being a heap corruption. The fact that you cannot reproduce a minimal example tells me that your code or the library is writing out of bounds in an unexpected place.

Comment: libraries + segfault = I would look for memory that is allocated in one library and released in another library (most likely in the process of freeing memory because the program exits).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was apparently that I was linking to a shared AND static version of the same library (a Boost library). Shouldn't the linker notice that and produce an error?